# Trying to display a nested object in a json api using vue, i'm pretty close just missing half a line of code

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object, fetch

So i'm declaring the variable and targetting the name of the object I want to render but because it's nested it won't show up on the DOM, need a little shove

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <div class="app">
        <h1> {{ fishName }} </h1> 



    </div>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
fetch('https://www.fishwatch.gov/api/species')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
let app = Vue.createApp ({ 
    data: function() {
        return {
        fishName: ["Species Name"],
    }
}
})
app.mount('.app')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Tried a couple of things but this is where im at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>    
<div class="app">
  <ul v-for="(fish, i) in fishes" :key="i">
    <li> {{ fish[fishName] }} </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
let app = Vue.createApp ({ 
  data() {
    return {
      fishes: [],
      fishName: ["Species Name"],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://www.fishwatch.gov/api/species')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.fishes = data
      })
  }
})
app.mount('.app')
</script>
```

Comment: @Lazy Loafs hey mate, if I understood you correctly put js code in script tag. I modified my answer, please take a look. Cheers :)

Comment: got it haha just needed to plug it in the right spot :D this is better tho for others, many thanks

Comment: Hi @nikola just for educations sake, can you explain to me where fish is defined and how you rendered it in the DOM